# Using Regexp in perl to pull information betwee two values

Tags: regex, perl

I am currently having issues with the below;

```
      open(my $fh, "<", "index.html") or die "cannot open index.html";

      foreach my $line  (<$fh>) {
              $line =~ '\"(.*?)\';
              print $line;
```

My Regex not working, i will show you below what i am trying to obtain;

```
<hr/>NUMBER.<br/><img class="cqm" border="0" src="UNIQUENUMBER..png"/>
<hr/>NUMBER.<br/><img class="cqm" border="0" src="UNIQUENUMBER..png"/>
```

Now i have replaced the real numbers due to DPA but these will all be unique, and the .html file is in the above format with 100s of entries like the above.

I need to strip this down with each line and it to only print the UNIQUENUMBER inbetween src=" and ..png

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Ashley

Comment: What is the result you expected?

Comment: Hi Jens,

I would expect the below print;

UNIQUENUMBER
UNIQUENUMBER
UNIQUENUMBER

And so on, as this should set the variable $line to only that if i am not mistaken.

Thank you,
Ashley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why you thought that regex would work. It just matches the first case of a string between a double quote and a single quote (which should exist anyway). What you're looking for is:

```
$line =~ /src="(.*?)\.*png"/;
print $1;
```

Comment: Thank you terdon.
I am pretty new to this so apologies for the original regex.

This is exactly what i needed.

Cheers,
Ashley

Comment: @user3780019 you're very welcome Ahsley. No worries, we were all new to this once. By the way, if this answer solves your issue, please take a minute and click the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will [signify to everyone](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved and is the way that thanks are expressed in the site.

Comment: This will also capture the `..png`, which may, or may not be desirable

Comment: @fugu good point, according to the OP it's not desired. Thanks, answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $in, '<', 'in.txt';

while(<$in>){
    chomp;
    my ($nums) = /src="(\d+?\.?\d+?)\.\.png/;
    print "$nums\n";
}
```

Will match `0.1`, `1` or `1.0`

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend that you use an actual HTML Parser when processing HTML.

The following uses [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) to pull all image tags with the class .cqm, and prints the src attribute if it ends in png:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Mojo::DOM;

#open my $fh, "<", "index.html";
my $fh = \*DATA;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(
    do { local $/; <$fh> }
);

for my $src ( $dom->find('img.cqm')->attr('src')->each ) {
    if ( $src =~ /(.*)\.png/ ) {
        print "$1\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
<hr/>NUMBER.<br/><img class="cqm" border="0" src="UNIQUENUMBER..png"/>
<hr/>NUMBER.<br/><img class="cqm" border="0" src="UNIQUENUMBER..png"/>
```

Outputs:

```
UNIQUENUMBER.
UNIQUENUMBER.
```

For a helpful 8 minute introductory video to this powerful framework, check out [Mojocast Episode 5](http://mojocasts.com/e5).